# Excel - (Array Formula) Sum IF Multiple Criteria with a Difference

Tags: excel, sum, array-formulas

I need to understand how (via an array formula) to sum up results based on multiple criteria. I understand there are plenty of questions on this topic already answered but mine seems to be different so the solutions given already don't work to the best of my knowledge.

As an example, see the below table. What I am wanting to do is sum all of Val for Type A where there is no Type C on the same day. (ie day 5 & 7)

```
Day     Type    Val
1       A       5
1       B       6
1       C       9
2       B       2
2       A       8
2       C       3
3       C       4
3       B       2
3       A       2
4       A       5
4       B       9
4       C       8
5       A       7
5       B       5
6       A       6
6       B       3
6       C       4
7       A       7
7       B       9
```

Comment: can you provide example of input and output?

Comment: @Danielle there is  an entire table of input provided.

Comment: @Morts81 Q:  There can only be a single A per day?  Will the List Always be sorted in order of Days?

Comment: @Forward_Ed yes, there will only ever be a max of 1x A per day. The list will not always be sorted.

Comment: Note however, there may not be just A, B & C, there could be 100's of 'Type' per day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Result]

1 cell array formula in J2 is:

```
=SUM((B2:B20="A")*C2:C20*ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A20,IF(A2:A20&B2:B20=A2:A20&"C",A2:A20),0)))
```

And to understand what's happening I have created I2 formula using helper columns. "_S1", "_S2" and "_S3" are named ranges below the headers.

I2 is normal formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(_S1,_S3)
```

_S1 is array formula

```
=(B2:B20="A")*C2:C20
```

Here I am just returning values for Type "A" and zeros for everything else.

_S2 is array formula

```
=IF(A2:A20&B2:B20=A2:A20&"C",A2:A20)
```

Here I am creating a range with day numbers where I have a "C" and some additional FALSEs.

_S3 is array formula

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A20,_S2,0))*1
```

Here I try to match a day from column A to 'C-days' from range _S2. If there is a match I return 0, otherwise 1.

Answer (score 0):

May I offer a slightly simplified version of that cool formula.

```
=SUM((B2:B20="A")*C2:C20*ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A20,(B2:B20="C")*A2:A20,0)))
```

Comment: Can you add some comments on the differences?