# Sum IF Multiple Criteria with a Difference - R

Tags: r, dataframe

So, I asked this question earlier but for array formulas in Excel. However, my dataset is so large that the spreadsheet becomes near on unresponsive so I want to be able to run it in R for efficiency purposes.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299420/excel-array-formula-sum-if-multiple-criteria-with-a-difference) to previously answered question

I'll reiterate and expand on it here though.

```
Day     Type    Val
1       A       5
1       B       6
1       C       9
1       D       7
2       B       2
2       A       8
2       C       3
2       D       3
3       C       4
3       B       2
3       A       2
4       A       5
4       B       9
4       C       8
5       A       7
5       B       5
6       A       6
6       B       3
6       C       4
7       A       7
7       B       9
```

I've provided a simplified data frame above (mine has 10's of thousands of rows and hundreds of 'Type'). I want to be able to assign a 'Type' and then

1. calculate the average 'Val' for the remaining 'Type' where the assigned 'Type' doesn't exist on that day
2. calculate the average 'Val' for the remaining 'Type' where the assigned 'Type' does exist on that day

For example, if I assign 'Type' C, then C does not exist on days 5 and 7.

The output would then be:

```
Type     Average_Without    Average_With
A        7.0                5.2
B        7.0                4.4
C        NA                 5.2
D        NA                 5.0
```

Comment: I must admit I have no idea what are you asking for.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, reading the excel Q linked I think I understand: choose type, compute average of A/B/C/D for days that "have" the chosen type on one side ond for days that "don't have" the chosen type on the other

Comment: Hmm... Maybe `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, indx := any(Type == "C"), by = Day] ; df[, .(Without = mean(Val[!(indx)]), With = mean(Val[(indx)])), by = Type]` then, dunno. You want this only for `C`?

Comment: @Cath I thought was that, but then I don't understand why is Average_Without for "A" not NA?

Comment: @adiana : average_without is the average for A but for days that don't "count" a "C" ("C" serves to separate the averages but averages are then computed by Type)

Comment: Guys, as I say in the question, I give an example where I have selected Type 'C', therefore the first row of the output table gives Type A average where C doesn't exist (Average_Without) and does exist (Average_With) on the relevant days, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way to get the values you want, using `data.table` package (but @DavidArenburg solution is better and will result in your desired output):

```
library(data.table)

# Average_with:
setDT(df)[Day %in% Day[Type=="C"], mean(Val), by=Type]
#   Type  V1
#1:    A 5.2
#2:    B 4.4
#3:    C 5.6
#4:    D 5.0

# Average_without
df[!Day %in% Day[Type=="C"], mean(Val), by=Type]
#   Type V1
#1:    A  7
#2:    B  7
```

**Edit, to get your output:**

```
setDT(df)[, C:=(Day %in% Day[Type=="C"])]
res <- df[, mean(Val), by=.(Type, C)]
dcast(res, Type~C, value.var="V1")
#   Type FALSE TRUE
#1:    A     7  5.2
#2:    B     7  4.4
#3:    C    NA  5.6
#4:    D    NA  5.0
```

**Or more direct, thanks to @Frank:**

```
setDT(df)[, C := Day %in% df[Type=="C", unique(Day)]]
dcast(df, Type~C, value.var="Val", fun=mean)
```

***Some benchmarks***

```
set.seed(123)
DF <- df <- data.frame(Day=sample(1:1000, 50000, replace=TRUE), 
                 Type=paste0(sample(letters[1:15], 50000, replace=TRUE), sample(letters[1:15], 50000, replace=TRUE)),
                 Val=rnorm(50000), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(microbenchmark)
# the test is made on "mo" (205 days with, 795 days without)
microbenchmark(cath1(df), cath2(df), cath_Frank(df), david1(df), david2(df), GG1(DF), GG2(DF), GG3(DF), GG4(DF), unit="relative")
         # expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq       max neval  cld
      # cath1(df)  1.3533329  1.4811559  1.4137217  1.502278  1.4146092 1.0523168   100 a   
      # cath2(df)  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.000000  1.0000000 1.0000000   100 a   
 # cath_Frank(df)  1.2985873  1.2980500  1.2380200  1.312180  1.2882213 0.9784906   100 a   
     # david1(df)  0.8642457  0.8717645  0.9768656  1.012679  0.9367868 0.9864712   100 a   
     # david2(df)  1.1708477  1.1723941  1.2105785  1.307281  1.2139049 0.9624526   100 a   
        # GG1(DF) 13.8436430 13.7552020 13.0925864 13.727017 15.9302047 3.0718886   100    d
        # GG2(DF)  4.8765172  4.8827384  4.9342907  4.943654  4.5173281 1.6818194   100  b  
        # GG3(DF)  8.8005347  8.8393882  9.6084771  9.048975 11.9310902 4.1580238   100   c 
        # GG4(DF)  4.4787631  4.5812781  4.5098152  4.623952  4.2268167 1.5829500   100  b
```

Comment: the Average_without formula works perfectly, however the Average_with formula doesn't produce the correct values for A and B. There are a couple of solutions offered further down that work. Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 9):

Using `data.table` you could also try

```
library(data.table)
# Get the days where Type == "C" - You probably don't need unique at all
indx <- unique(setDT(df)[Type == "C", Day]) 

# Calculate average by including/excluding these days by Type
df[, 
   .(Without = mean(Val[!Day %in% indx]), 
     With = mean(Val[Day %in% indx])), 
   by = Type]
#    Type Without With
# 1:    A       7  5.2
# 2:    B       7  4.4
# 3:    C     NaN  5.6
# 4:    D     NaN  5.0
```

We could probably enhance it a little bit more by reducing calculations but by a bit harder to read code

```
indx <- unique(setDT(df)[Type == "C", Day]) 
df[, {
      indx2 <- Day %in% indx ## Calculate this only once and reuse it
      .(
        Without = mean(Val[!indx2]), 
        With = mean(Val[indx2])
       )
     }, 
   by = Type]
#    Type Without With
# 1:    A       7  5.2
# 2:    B       7  4.4
# 3:    C     NaN  5.6
# 4:    D     NaN  5.0
```

Answer (score 7):

My understanding is that what is wanted is the mean of `Val` by `Type` for those days having a `C` among their rows and the mean of `Val` by `Type` for those days not having a `C` among their rows.

The first three solutions do not use any packages.

**1) aggregate** This uses `aggregate` over each subset of rows.  We first create `hasC` which is a logical vector with one component per row of `DF` that indicates whether that row belongs to a day that has a `C`.

```
hasC <- ave(DF$Type == "C", DF$Day, FUN = any)

m <- merge(aggregate(Val ~ Type, DF[!hasC, ], mean), 
           aggregate(Val ~ Type, DF[hasC, ], mean), by = 1, all = TRUE)
names(m) <- c("Type", "Avg_wo", "Avg_with")
```

giving this data.frame:

```
> m
  Type Avg_wo Avg_with
1    A      7      5.2
2    B      7      4.4
3    C     NA      5.6
4    D     NA      5.0
```

**2) tapply** `hasCf` is similar to `hasC` but has been made a factor:

```
hasC <- ave(DF$Type == "C", DF$Day, FUN = any)
hasCf <- factor(hasC, levels = c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c("Avg_without", "Avg_with"))
tapply(DF$Val, list(DF$Type, hasCf), mean)
```

giving this matrix where the row names are the types:

```
  Avg_without Avg_with
A           7      5.2
B           7      4.4
C          NA      5.6
D          NA      5.0
```

**3) xtabs**  `hasCf` is same as in (2).  The first `xtabs` calculates the sums and the second calculates the count.  The ratio is the mean:

```
hasC <- ave(DF$Type == "C", DF$Day, FUN = any)
hasCf <- factor(hasC, levels = c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c("Avg_without", "Avg_with"))
xtabs(Val ~ Type + hasCf, DF) / xtabs(~ Type + hasCf, DF)
```

giving this `c("xtabs", "table")` class object:

```
    hasCf
Type Avg_without Avg_with
   A         7.0      5.2
   B         7.0      4.4
   C                  5.6
   D                  5.0
```

**4) dplyr** Here is a solution that uses dplyr and tidyr packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
   group_by(Day) %>% 
   mutate(hasC = factor("C" %in% Type, levels = c(FALSE, TRUE), 
                        labels = c("Avg_without", "Avg_with"))) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(Type, hasC) %>% 
   summarize(mean = mean(Val)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   spread(hasC, mean)
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

    Type Avg_without Avg_with
  (fctr)       (dbl)    (dbl)
1      A           7      5.2
2      B           7      4.4
3      C          NA      5.6
4      D          NA      5.0
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- structure(list(Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), Type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Val = c(5L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 
    8L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 9L)), .Names = c("Day", "Type", 
"Val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: Excellent, this is perfect